# Difference in mime-type in form PHP

Tags: php, mime-types

I would like upload .docx, but

In `$_FILES['field']['type']` is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`, but in `mime_content_type()` return `application/zip`

Why these types are diffrent?
Which is good?

Answer (score 1):

The DOCX format consists of a number of different files all wrapped up in a zip file. The software you are using is examining the file, seeing it is a zip file and reporting it with the standard MIME type for zip.

"Good" is somewhat subjecting, but `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` is probably better as it is more specific.

Comment: The same is with .rar files, $_FILES return 'application/octet-stream' and php function return 'application/x-rar'.